# TradingView/Binance indicator's historical data

Tags: c#, binance, tradingview-api

I wanted to get Binance indicator data for a specific date because they are calculating indicator's data for years ago and when I calculate EMA/MACD myself, it differs. Binance is using TradingView's charts.

Since I don't find an API that does that, do you guys know a workaround to get this data? Even if that includes `WebClient`/`HttpWebRequest`.

TradingView's chart: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/

Binance's chart: https://www.binance.com/en/trade/pro/BTC_USDT?interval=1m

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can get Chart data and then use [Skender.Stock.Indicators](https://daveskender.github.io/Stock.Indicators/) Library to get your indicator

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. The TV don't allow to import thirdparty data

Comment: I'm not talking about importing third party data. I'm talking about getting their data. Getting EMA(5), EMA(10), EMA(20) for a specific date.

Comment: If you want to get indicator's data from BINANCE.com and display them in your TV chart this is impossible too.